# NullPointerException when writing information from linkedhashmap to a file

Tags: java

I am trying to write information from a `LinkedHashmap` to a file, but this code is giving me a `NullPointerException`:

```
public void writeFile(String file, Map<Word, Defination> wmap) {

    File FileName = new File(file);
    try {

        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(FileName, true);
        PrintStream pstrim = new PrintStream(stream);
        String line = null;
        rmap=wmap;
        Iterator<Word> it = wmap.keySet().iterator(); //generic iterator
        while (it.hasNext() && found == 0) {
            String key = it.next().getWord();
            System.out.println(key);
            Defination defns = new Defination(wmap.get(key).getDef()); //null pointer exception here
            line = key + "=" + defns.getDef();

            if (line != null) {
                pstrim.println(line);
            }
        }
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException IO) {
    }

}
```

Why is there a `NullPointerException` and how can I fix it?

Comment: your wmap.get(key) seems to return null.. do you have the value corresponding to the key??

Comment: `.getDef()` could also be ruturning null.

Comment: @RyanCarlson - That will not give NullPointerException... if getDef() returns null, we are not using it on anything else...

Comment: Try and add a bunch of System.out.println([differentnumbers]) to your code to narrow down where the problem is occurring. Then you'll know what line to focus on. You could also print out some relevant information in some of the the println-s.

Comment: @TheLostMind Good point, I forgot that constructors and methods can take `null`s as parameters.

Comment: @TheLostMind return value of `getDef()` is used in the constructor of `Defination` so It could cause a NPE if a member variable or method is accessed without null-check. Without stacktrace one cannot exacly tell. But OP seems to exclusde this possibility since it points the line of `Map#get`

Comment: @A4L - I agree... But I think that the probablity of that happening is less..

Answer (score 3):

Obviously your map contains a Key which maps to a `null`. Some Implementations of the Map interface allow the null key and/or the null value.

from the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

> Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.
>   More formally, if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)
>
> **A return value of null does not necessarily indicate that the map contains no mapping for the key; it's also possible that the map explicitly maps the key to null. The containsKey operation may be used to distinguish these two cases.**

Answer (score 2):

You should check if the map contains the given key. If not, keep iterating:

```
if (!wmap.containsKey(key)) {
    continue;
}
```